# Zoom Presentation where I share screen but can annotate or scribble via my tablet

Tags: presentation, engineering, video-conference

I present using zoom to my Engineering Univeristy class using my Dell laptiop. I use powerpoint while sharing my Powerpoint app. So far so good.

Now sometimes based on a student question I want to scribble or draw on the slides, or annotate a point etc. Zoom does allow annotation and right now I scribble using my mouse. It works but isn't ideal. My laptop does not have a touchscreen or stylus.

What would be nice is to have a way to "mirror" the slides on my Android tablet where I do have a Stylus and then I could scribble etc. much easier and precisely.

Is this possible to set up the ecosystem in some way as to make this possible? How?  Either via zoom or the Windows OS or a third party app.

PS. I could, of course, switch to zoom on the Tablet entirely. But for multiple reasons that is NOT desirable. e.g. Responding to chats is easier from my laptop keyboard; I share other apps from laptop at times; all my files are on the laptop drive etc.

PS2. Sometimes I am forced to use Webex. So if someone knows the answer to the same question but via Webex I would love to hear that as well.

Comment: Switch to the tablet, scribble and then switch back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in to the zoom meeting *both* from your laptop and from your tablet. Then use the annotate function on your *tablet* to annotate the slides which you share from your laptop.

(You have to allow the tablet user, or generally other users, to annotate the slides, of course.  I'm not entirely sure whether you can restrict this possibility to a specific user - though you might want to try with making the tablet user co-host or the like - but on the other hand, it might have advantages if also the students can annotate your slides, e.g. in case they want to ask a question about some specific point.)

(Also, I believe you cannot log in twice with the same account - but you don't even need an account on the tablet, or otherwise you can create a second account.)

Comment: Thanks! I think this should work! My mistake was I assumed that only host could annotate.